# How to set cookies for two-letter domains in IE8?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, cookies, internet-explorer-8

Because it's not trivial to tell short domain names apart from TLDs, [Microsoft maintains a list](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ieinternals/archive/2009/09/19/private-domain-names-and-public-suffixes-in-internet-explorer.aspx) of special cases for IE8. The list can be found in `res://urlmon.dll/ietldlist.xml`.

However, I don't understand how to actually make use of that list. Even the privileged two-letter domains that *are* listed seem to misbehave.

For example, the domain [cn.ca](http://cn.ca/) can be found on the list. But here's what I get in IE8's javascript console:

[image: Cookie setting fails on ca.cn with IE8]

The same method works perfectly on a longer domain, such as stackoverflow.com (I cleared my cookies before this example to avoid unrelated noise):

[image: Cookie setting works on stackoverflow.com with IE8]

Is the list of special cases actually broken, or do I simply misunderstand its purpose? Is there *any* way to set cookies (not limited to a subdomain) for short domains in IE8?

Answer (score 6):

No good info in the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms533693%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). However, I found a good write up on this in an [MSDN blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ieinternals/archive/2009/08/20/wininet-ie-cookie-internals-faq.aspx).

Most relevant to your question is Q6:

> **IE won’t set a cookie for certain domains, like those of the format http://xx.yy?**
>
> Correct. The idea is that you may not set a cookie on a "top-level"
>   domain shared by unrelated organizations. Historically, ccTLDs of the
>   format xx.yy were effective TLDs, so cookies may not be set on them.
>   While this heuristic was never perfect, it's been unchanged for over
>   15 years and hence is not likely to change any time soon. The
>   intricacy of this issue merits a long blog post all its own—[see this
>   post](http://blogs.msdn.com/ieinternals/archive/2009/09/19/Private-Domain-Names-and-Public-Suffixes-in-Internet-Explorer.aspx).

Other interesting tidbits:

> **IE's cookie code doesn't seem to support  as defined in
>   RFC2109 or RFC2965.**
>
> Internet Explorer (including IE8) does not attempt to support any RFC
>   for cookies. WinINET (the network stack below IE) has cookie implementation based on the pre-RFC Netscape draft spec for cookies.
>
> **If I don’t specify a leading dot when setting the DOMAIN attribute, IE
>   doesn’t care?**
>
> Correct. All current version browsers (Chrome, FF, Opera, etc) seem to treat a leading dot as implicit

From [Microsoft Support](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2004188) (Affects IE 6.0, 7.0, and 8.0) :

> **Symptoms:** A user opens a webpage from http://servername.xxx.yy. The web site at that address sets a cookie and specifies "xxx.yy" as the domain for that cookie.  However, Internet Explorer does not save the cookie information.
>
> **Cause:** For security reasons, Internet Explorer does not save cookie data for domains like xxx.yy, where .yy is a two-letter country code domain and the three letters xxx are one of the generic top level domain names: com, edu, gov, int, mil, net, or org.  Domains of this form are treated as top level domains, effectively a country-specific version of the generic top level domain.  For security reasons, wininet prevents setting cookies for such domains.  In this case, xxx.yy is effectively a top level domain, and is protected in the same way as ".com" would be.
>
> **Resolution:** This behavior is by design.

Comment: In other words, `co.uk` is not a domain that belongs to someone and such assumption is made for all ccTLDs. Great answer.

Comment: But... isn't that why they added the res://urlmon.dll/ietldlist.xml list in the first place? To avoid making that assumption without exception. I'm so very confused. The Q6 answer even *links to the blog post detailing the list* while simultaneously contradicting it!

Comment: @jjs That list is for exceptions to the rule, but you can't factor that into your day-to-day JavaScript. That list is only supposed to be updated by Microsoft during browser releases.

Comment: I understand that it is managed and updated by Microsoft, but if Microsoft has already added a domain as an exception to the list, shouldn't the domain then be usable in Javascript?