# NodeJS & Express cookie issue with IE

Tags: node.js, express, subdomain, session-cookies, express-session

I'm having some issues with the cookie for a sessionID returned by Express to the browser. For consecutive requests the received cookie is not being passed back, hence generating a new session for each request. The login-state can not be maintained.

This issue only seems to be occurring on IE11 and below on an OS lower than Win10 or so (eg: IE11 on Win7). Edge, Chrome, Safari, FF... no issues.

Some more context:
We have two applications, say one.example.com and two.example.com. With requests from both applications the logged-in user should be kept track of.
The MEAN stack accessible on two.example.com returns set-cookie headers for one day, HTTP only, with a domain of '.example.com' on path '/'.

When I load a page with say, 10 resources, all these requests receive a new cookie for the sessionID. Even on consecutive page loads. The cookie is never returned back to the server.

**HTTP trace from Chrome:**

```
GET http://localhost:3000/
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
set-cookie: test=123
set-cookie: webSessionId=s%3Av6R-...

GET http://localhost:3000/lib/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css
Cookie: test=123; webSessionId=s%3Av6R-...
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Set-Cookie: test=123
```

seen Chrome returns the session, it is not returned by express for the second request

**HTTP trace from IE:**
[image: response for first requested resource]
*response for first requested resource*
[image: request for second resource]
*request for second resource*
[image: response for second requested resource]
*response for second requested resource*

The test123 is a hardcoded cookie I set on every request (regardless whether it has been returned)... by using `res.setHeader('Set-Cookie', 'test=123');`. At one point I was looking at the difference between a 'set-cookie' and 'Set-Cookie' (as can be seen in above screenshots), but that does not seem to impact IE.

So I started to play around with the other cookie properties (expiry date, domain, path, secure & http only) as soon as I provide a domain... the test-cookie is not returned by IE.
In our setup '.example.com' really is a requirement. The domain does not contain an underscore (_). In dev & tst it does contain a hyphen "two-dev.example.com". But the IE(11) problem also exists on prd (two.example.com).

Anyone has any idea as to why IE refuses to return cookies with a domain?
This sh*t is driving me bananas

using: express 4.13.1; express-session 1.11.3; cookie-parser 1.3.2

Answer (score 0):

I think I found the cause... the domains we are using are two-letter domains e.g. `one.xx.yy` & `two.xx.yy`. So setting the Domain-part of the cookie to `.xx.yy` is causing IE to ignore the cookie, I recon.

Anyone can confirm this issue is still valid on IE11?

> [How to set cookies for two-letter domains in IE8?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20074524/how-to-set-cookies-for-two-letter-domains-in-ie8)

And/or how to circumvent this? Besides the obvious of using other domains.